# Django cutting off uploaded file

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm making a Django app in which a user can upload a file (an image) using AJAX.

While developing locally, I saw that PIL, which I used to process the image after upload, had a bug. After investigating I found out it's because PIL is getting the file data cut off. It's only getting the first 1MB of the file, which is why it's failing. (The file is around 3MB.)

Why could this be, and how can I solve it? My immediate suspicion is that `runserver`, which I use locally, caps AJAX uploads for some reason. But I can't be sure. And if it does, I don't know how to make it stop.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which components are relevant for the file upload? Sounds like one of them has a max file size limit. Django dev server has no such limit as far as I'm aware.

Comment: How are you handling the upload?  Also, have you tried setting the upload max memory size to something larger than the default 2.5 MB?  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE)  Also, have you tried uploading without Ajax to see if the ajax portion matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a "feature" of the client-side AJAX package we were using (`flow.js`) and we just had to increase `chunkSize`.